# converting json annotation to coco format

Tags: json, detectron, coco

I have annotated my data using vott and the default format is json. I wanted to load my data to detectron2 model but it seems that the required format is coco.
Can anyone tell me how can I convert my data from json vott to coco format ??

Answer (score 0):

My classmates and I have created a python package called [PyLabel](https://pypi.org/project/pylabel) to help others with this kind of task and other labelling tasks. You can see an example in this notebook: https://github.com/pylabel-project/samples/blob/main/coco2voc.ipynb.

You might be able to use the package's importer tool to import your data and convert it to coco.

You can find the code for the package here: https://github.com/pylabel-project/.